# How to sum up these grouped rows that also have an order by

Tags: mysql

Imagine this is the data in my table:

```
Amount/ Number /Type
100/ 1.2 / A
120 / 1.2 /A
130/ 1.1 / A
90 / 0.3 / A
50/ 2.4 / B
150 / 1.9 /B
150 / 1.9 / B
```

I want this data in two groups one for type A, one for type B. Then within these two groups I want them ordered by price, ascending for one and descending for the other. This I can do:

```
(SELECT * FROM `table` WHERE `type`='A' GROUP BY `number` LIMIT 10)
UNION ALL 
(SELECT * FROM `table` WHERE `type`='b' GROUP BY `number` LIMIT 15) ORDER BY `type`), 
(CASE WHEN `type`='A' THEN `number` END) ASC, 
(CASE WHEN `type`='B' THEN `number` END) DESC";
```

**However the problem is I want to add up types of the same number.. so for 1.2 I would get 220/1.2/A, but instead with my query I just get 100/1.2/A... how do I add up the numbers amounts of the same amount and same type?**

Thanks

Comment: Please show desired output based on provided sample data

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the query that you want:

```
(SELECT sum(amount) as amount, number, type
 FROM `table`
 WHERE `type`='A'
 GROUP BY `number` LIMIT 10
)
UNION ALL 
(SELECT sum(amount) as amount, number, type
 FROM `table`
 WHERE `type`='b'
 GROUP BY `number` LIMIT 15
)
ORDER BY `type`, 
          (CASE WHEN `type`='A' THEN `number` END) ASC, 
          (CASE WHEN `type`='B' THEN `number` END) DESC;
```

As a note:  this will return 10 rows of A and 15 rows of B *after* the `group by`.  I'm guessing that this is what you really want.

Also, the `group by` will automatically order by `number`.  If you want a random order, then add `group by rand()` to each subquery before the `limit`.

Comment: @user1796995 . . . You realize that there is a difference between this answer and the answer you accepted.  This solution returns 25 rows, 10 of "A" and 15 of "B".  That solution summarizes 10 rows of "A" and 15 of "B".  The final number of rows may be smaller than 25.  You weren't clear on which version you wanted, but there is a difference.

Comment: Thank you Gordon for pointing that out. Your interpretation is the answer I wanted. I have chosen your answer instead (sorry Peter).

Answer (score 2):

Are you looking for this?

```
SELECT SUM(amount) amount, number, type 
  FROM table1
 GROUP BY type, number
 ORDER BY type,
       CASE WHEN `type`='A' THEN `number` END ASC, 
       CASE WHEN `type`='B' THEN `number` END DESC;
```

Output:

```
| AMOUNT | NUMBER | TYPE |
--------------------------
|     90 |    0.3 |    A |
|    130 |    1.1 |    A |
|    220 |    1.2 |    A |
|     50 |    2.4 |    B |
|    300 |    1.9 |    B |
```

**[SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/59acc/3)**

**UPDATE:** If you need to limit the number of source records of each type use this. *Note that when you use `LIMIT` you have to explicitly state `ORDER BY` since the order of rows is not preserved.*

```
SELECT SUM(amount) amount, number, type 
FROM (
  (SELECT * FROM table1 WHERE type = 'A' ORDER BY number LIMIT 10)
  UNION ALL
  (SELECT * FROM table1 WHERE type = 'B' ORDER BY number LIMIT 15)
  ) q
 GROUP BY type, number
 ORDER BY type,
       CASE WHEN `type`='A' THEN `number` END ASC, 
       CASE WHEN `type`='B' THEN `number` END DESC;
```

**[SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/59acc/5)**

Comment: Thanks that is the desired output, however I need the query structure to retain the 'union' I think, because I want the limits to be in place (limit 15 and limit 10).. unless you can see another way

Comment: @user1796995 See updated answer. Note that if you use `LIMIT` you have to  explicitly use `ORDER BY` since the order of rows is not preserved

Comment: Thanks but in your updated answer, mysql gives the error 'Every derived table must have its own alias'. Also, before the 'group by' what is the 'q' for?

Comment: @user1796995 That is the alias for inner query and it's required. Did you take a look at sqlfiddle I provided for the updated query. It should work just fine.

Comment: I'm up voting because you have a perfectly reasonable interpretation of the question, even though the OP was slightly different.

Comment: @GordonLinoff Thanks ;). I got it when you already have posted your version.

Answer (score 0):

Something like this perhaps?

```
select Number,Type,sum(Amount) from x group by Number,Type
+--------+------+--------+
| Number | Type | sum(a) |
+--------+------+--------+
|    0.3 | A    |     90 |
|    1.1 | A    |    130 |
|    1.2 | A    |    220 |
|    1.9 | B    |    300 |
|    2.4 | B    |     50 |
+--------+------+--------+
5 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

Comment: Thank you but I also need to incorporate the 2 different limit conditions (LIMIT 10 and LIMIT 15)